# Find the closed-form for $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i(\frac{1}{2})^i$

Tags: summation, closed-form, geometric-series

I start with simplifying:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i(\frac{1}{2})^i=\sum_{i=0}^n(-\frac{1}{2})^i$$

then:

$$S = 1 + (-\frac{1}{2}) + (-\frac{1}{2})^2 + ... +(-\frac{1}{2})^n$$

$$(-\frac{1}{2})S = (-\frac{1}{2}) + (-\frac{1}{2})^2 + ... +(-\frac{1}{2})^n+(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}$$

$$(-\frac{1}{2}-1)S = (-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} - 1$$

am I on the right track?

Comment: That all looks fine, although both numerator and denominator are less than $1$, so you can swap the signs write it as a positive quotient.

Comment: @Chappers: Thanks for that, is it better now?

Comment: Hang on, you've lost a $-$. Okay, now you can't really do any better, unless you want to mess around with writing it as a quotient of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete answer:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i(\frac{1}{2})^i=\sum_{i=0}^n(-\frac{1}{2})^i$$

then:

$$S = 1 + (-\frac{1}{2}) + (-\frac{1}{2})^2 + ... +(-\frac{1}{2})^n$$

$$(-\frac{1}{2})S = (-\frac{1}{2}) + (-\frac{1}{2})^2 + ... +(-\frac{1}{2})^n+(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}$$

$$(-\frac{1}{2}-1)S = (-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} - 1$$

divide both sides by $(-\frac{1}{2}-1)$, we have:

$$S = \frac{(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} - 1}{(-\frac{1}{2}-1)}=\frac{(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} - 1}{(-1.5)}=\frac{1-(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{1.5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using the formula for *[finite geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)*
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=0}^nx^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i&=\sum_{i=0}^n\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^i\\
> &=\frac{1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right)
>   \end{align*}